# How to know a JSON array is an empty array in bash?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, json

I use this code to consume GitHub API and automate some tasks:

```
curl --silent -H 'Authorization: token github_access_token' 'https://api.github.com/orgs/OrganizationName/repos?per_page=100'
```

Sometimes I get this as the response:

```
[

]
```

I want to know if the response is an empty array or not.

I thought of using `jq` like `echo $Response | jq -r ".[]"` but I don't know how to continue from there.

How can I find out a JSON string is an empty array in bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could test with the array length:

```bash
if [[ $(jq length <<<"$Response") -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Empty"
else
    echo "Not empty"
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

If you `jq`, you can test whether the input is an empty list:

```
% echo '["a"]' | jq '. == []'
false
% echo '[]' | jq '. == []'
true
% echo '[]' | jq -e '. | length == 0'
true
% echo '["a"]' | jq -e '. | length == 0'
false
```

And you can use the `-e` option:

> ```
> --exit-status / -e:
> ```
>
> Sets the exit status of jq to 0 if the last output value was neither
> false nor null, 1 if the last output value was either false or null,
> or 4 if no valid result was ever produced. Normally jq exits with 2 if
> there was any usage problem or system error, 3 if there was a jq
> program compile error, or 0 if the jq program ran.

So:

```sh
if curl --silent -H 'Authorization: token github_access_token' 'https://api.github.com/orgs/OrganizationName/repos?per_page=100' |
   jq -e '. == []'
then
  echo Empty output
else
  echo Got something
fi
```

Comment: ... there's also an explicit [isempty](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#isempty) function